# Arduino SIM800L: converting String to char* error

Tags: c++, arduino

I am currently learning Arduino programming and working on sending SMS with SIM800L module.

from the SIM800L library sample sketches, there is a function for sending SMS

```
char* text;
char* number;
bool error;                     //to catch the response of sendSms


void setup(){
   GSM.begin(4800);             
   text="Testing Sms";          //text for the message. 
   number="2926451386";         //change to a valid number.
   error=SIM800L .sendSms(number,text);
}
```

I need to change the mobile number to the ones from the response on my API.
I am able to get response when I call the API. the API returns a mobile number.

`+639051234567` it is in `String` data type.

When I try to pass the mobile number to the `sendSms` function I get an error saying `cannot convert 'String' to 'char*' in assignment`

Here's mu full Arduino code.

```
#include <Sim800L.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>     
#include <UIPEthernet.h>

#define RX  10
#define TX  11

Sim800L GSM(RX, TX);

int buzzer = 8;
int smokeA0 = A5;
int smokeA1 = A4;
int smokeA2 = A3;

int sensorThres1 = 650;
int sensorThres2 = 500;
int sensorThres3 = 500;


byte mac[6] = {0x54, 0x55, 0x58, 0x10, 0x00, 0x24};    
EthernetClient client;
char server[] = "192.168.2.100";
int  interval = 5000; 
char uid[] = "1"; 
String response = String(100); 
char* text;
char* number;

void setup() {

  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(smokeA0, INPUT);
  pinMode(smokeA1, INPUT);
  pinMode(smokeA2, INPUT);


  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac);

  Serial.print("IP Address        : ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  GSM.begin(4800);
}

void loop() {
   int analogSensor1 = analogRead(smokeA0);
   int analogSensor2 = analogRead(smokeA1);
   int analogSensor3 = analogRead(smokeA2);


  if (analogSensor1 > sensorThres1 || analogSensor2 > sensorThres2 || analogSensor3 > sensorThres3){

if(client.connect(server, 80)){
        Serial.println("-> Connected");
        // Make a HTTP request:
        client.print( "GET /apartment/insert.php?");
        client.print("uid=");
        client.print(uid);
        client.println( " HTTP/1.1");
        client.print( "Host: " );
        client.println(server);
        client.println( "Connection: close" );
        client.println();
        client.println();

       while (client.connected()) {
          if (client.available()) {
            char c = client.read();
            //Serial.print(c);
            response= response + c;
          }
       }

       int contentBodyIndex = response.lastIndexOf('\n');
       if (contentBodyIndex > 0) {
          String str = response.substring(contentBodyIndex);
          int respLen = str.length() + 1;
          char charArr[respLen];

          number = str.toCharArray(charArr, respLen); // getting error 'void value not ignored as it ought to be'

          text = "Smoke was detected in your apartment unit";
          error=GSM.sendSms(number ,text);
       }



        client.stop();
        delay(1000); 
        tone(buzzer, 1000);
        delay(10000); 
        noTone(buzzer);
        delay(1000);    
      }else{
        Serial.println("--> connection failed/n");
      }
 }
 else
 {
   noTone(buzzer);
 }
 delay(1000);
}
```

appreciate any help.. Thanks guys.

Comment: Did you try Google first?  You can just create a std::string object using the  const char* constructor i.e. `std::string numberStr(number);`

Comment: I tried using the std:string but it says `string is not a member of std` I also included the `<string>` library but it gives error when compiling.

Comment: @JustinRandall This is about Arduino. There is no `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think just converting a String `response` to `char *` array is enough:

```
...
String str = response.substring(contentBodyIndex);
int respLen = str.length() + 1
char charArr[respLen];
str.toCharArray(charArr, respLen);

text = "Smoke was detected in your apartment unit";
error=GSM.sendSms(charArr ,text);
...
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this but it gives `invalid use of void expression`,  I'm really confused how to do it.

Comment: The thing is that your `response.substring()` is returning a `String` but `number` is `char` array. So you have to convert a String to char array.

Comment: I am trying to fix it and seems to be fixed, but now the error says. 

`expected primary-expression before '.' ` token it is pointing to his line 

`Sim800L.sendSms(str,text);`

Comment: Before which `'.'`? Please let me know more so I can help you

Comment: Change it to GSM.sendSms(str,text);  You're invoking the class type (Sim800L) instead of the object you declared (GSM).

Comment: It seems Sim800L is a class, not object. You have created `Sim800L GSM(RX, TX)` at the beginning so maybe you should try `GSM.sendSms();

Comment: I changed it to `GSM` now it is giving `no matching function for call to 'Sim800L::sendSms(String&, char*&)'`

Comment: probably the error is with the first parameter as it should accept a char.. but when I put it like this `number = str.toCharArray(charArr, respLen);` and pass the variable to the function `sendSms(number, text)`, I get this error `void value not ignored as it ought to be`

Comment: don't do `number = str.toCharArray()`. toCharArray() returns void

Comment: @KimCarlo you should call `GSM.sendSms(charArr, text')`

Comment: It's another question. If you got the answer to your current question what about accepting the answer!?

Answer (score 0):

Unless `sendSms` modifies the number, there is no need to copy the `String` object into a char array.

You can just pass the pointer of the `String` object's internal char array with `c_str`.

```
String num = response.substring(contentBodyIndex+1); // +1 to get rid of the '+'
error = SIM800L.sendSms(num.c_str(), text);
```